# Xamarin.Auth unable to login with Google [Xamarin.Forms]

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I am using `Xamarin.Auth` for the Facebook and Google Login but every time I am getting an error displayed in the Screenshot.

Google Login:
Code:

```
var googleauth = new OAuth2Authenticator(  
    "ClientId",  
    "ClientSecret", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",  
    new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),  
    new Uri("http://www.someurl.com"),
    new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")  
);
```

Error:
[image]
[image]

What should I do to resolve this issues?

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue you can try the [demo](https://github.com/mikexxma/GoogleOAuthDemo)

Comment: facebook issues was from the developers.facebook.com that was my fault, but I am still getting issue in Google Login. (Updated Question)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the console for your project and look under API Access.
https://console.developers.google.com

You should see your client ID & secret there, along with a list of redirect URIs. If the URI you want isn't listed, click edit settings and add the URI to the list.

Comment: I know that, here the problem is with `Xamarin.Auth`

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not problem with Xamarin.Auth, but PEBKAC.

The redirect_uri_mismatch means that uri reigstered on google console differes from one sent by the client, could be ! Xamarin.Auth.

Comment: Google has blocked authentication for Mobile Browser. We must have to use the SDK for mobile google login.

Comment: No. You do not have to use SDKs (I assume I think something like Facebook SDK or google SDK).
New google's restrictions mean you cannot user embedded WebViews (Android WebView and iOS UIWebView or WKWebView), but you can use CustomTabs (Chrome Custom Tabs) on Android or SFSafariViewcontroller on iOS. Those are actually out of process tools - system browser. This has nothing to do with redirect_uri_mismatch which is raised it you define one redirect_url on server side and send different one in Oauth request. It happened to me a lot of times during tests and debugging. Setup (user) error.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.. also Xamarin.Auth has recently updated SDK and I will check this issue again.

Comment: @ChandreshKhambhayata
I'm Xamarin.Auth maintainer, so ask me anything. If you need real-time help (hand in hand leading through implementation) go to Xamarin Chat (community slack team) #xamarin-auth-social channel.
Here:
https://xamarinchat.slack.com/messages/C4TD1NHPT
There are 10+ people with finished implementations of their OAuth needs and they are willing to help, including me.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to enter in slack, it is asking for login credentials.